# Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver Multithreading for Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, jdbc

I'm using MS SQL Server JDBC version 4.0 to call stored procedures. I'm using threads heavily in my app, and I'd like to execute MS Stored Procedures in parallel. Can someone please point me to a resource I can use. I've been wading the web for a while and no success, yet. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
Just came across [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/07afa257-dac5-4cd3-b661-1bac72291351/is-jdbc-40-driver-thread-safe). Going through it now. Doesn't explain anything tangible. Goes off-topic.

**UPDATE**: 
The discussion at [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2c304796-6345-4dd1-95c5-8546fc7ab4eb/multithreading-inserts-problem) thread seems to offer some insight. A suggestion from someone who's experienced this problem before will be appreciated very much.

Comment: Be aware that you need a separate connection object per thread, or you will get all sorts of problems. Remember to use the connection pool to recycle them rather than passing them around all the time.